# Is this a viable method of securing frontend with JWT?

Tags: javascript, jwt

currently im trying to learn how to setup Mern-Apps with authentication. When logging in the user gets a jwt token which works perfectly fine. I store the jwt in a cookie and on the backend the auth works fine. My frontend runs on port 4000 and my node server on 3000.

I have issues with understanding the authentication or protection in the frontend.
My first approach was to implement a post request to my backend when a component renders. If the verification in the backend is successful it responds "Succes" and the frontend renders the wanted component. If the backend verification doesn't work the frontend should redirect to the login page

My problem here is:
Isn't it possible for the user to just edit the js files in the browser to completely remove the auth request or just remove the redirect and skip auth like that easily?

My second Approach was to check if the client has a token stored in a cookie and give him access then but then i noticed users can easily create their own cookies and remove this in the js files aswell.

Am i understanding something wrong here? Is it possible to edit the page like that and skip auth?
Do i need to run both back and frontend on the same port?
What is the best approach to do the frontend auth? For me personally the first approach but if every js file is editable in the frontend how do you even do frontend auth?

In my case i tried using an useEffect hook which sends a request to the server when the site renders.

Comment: The general catch-all answer to your question is that you should never, ever trust the input you get from the client-side, for the reasons you've listed. JWT and other methods of authentication can help to mitigate some security concerns, but your server side request handlers should also be enforcing all rules in place within your domain business logic

Comment: Not only can you edit JS files, you can call the API from terminal with cURL. Backend must validate the value of the JWT - that it's present and that it's valid.

Comment: I understand that. How am i supposed to verify the token in the backend without sending a request from the frontend???

To specify: If I use the useEffect hook on initial render. can this be interrupted?

Comment: `I store the jwt in a cookie and on the backend the auth works fine` - just want to make sure that the cookie is an HTTP Only cookie and your FE isn't doing something like `document.cookies` when it receives the JWT

Comment: Thank you. Im just doing an axios/fetch call to the server with an useEffect hook which means it gets executed before mounting/rendering. My question is if this is save or if this is interruptable or skippable by the client.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your front-end is completely editable by user.

*TL;DR:* You can not secure front-end parts, only API in back-end

So take another approach:

1. Trust settings sent from back-end
2. Show components based on these settings
3. To render sensitive information, user need info from back-end
4. Back-end validates JWT and shows or denies this content
5. Even if someone mocked response, they will see and be able to work in their front-end. Back-end is still strong with JWT validations

Comment: Tank you i understood that. But how do i even send a request from the front to the backend without the uer being able to interrupt that?

An example:
A user calls example.com/dashboard and he should only be able to see the site if logged in. So i send a client sided request to the backend express server which asks if the user is logged in. If the res is Success the site gets rendered and otherwise another page renders. So how in the world can i send a request whic cant be interrupted by the user. I can't tell express when to render components in react.

Comment: @Tim 1. Encrypt JWT, so you know if it was tempered. 2. I assume you are using API calls, so even if UI is rendered, there will be nothing to show. 3. Logout user on error to back-end

Comment: so i can useeffect with an axios/fetch call pre mounting/rendering and it will always work and can't be interrupted by the user?

Comment: @Tim Everything can be interrupted by user. Just make sure your back-end is secure enought